# how to draw 2 centimeters long line on screen in adobe air

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4

I need to draw 2 centimeters long line on screen on an Adobe Air application. I don't know how to do it!

**Explanation:**
I am getting parameters from another application say x centimeters, and that parameter is in centimeters. 
I need to draw a circle exactly x centimeters from the top of the screen.

best regards

Comment: At first I wanted to suggest a transformation from this page (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/authoring_for_multiple_screen_sizes.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_1). But it seems to be wrong to use Capabilities.screenDPI. On my computer I get always 72 pixel although it is much more. I hope somebody will show us a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you won't be able to do it on desktop since AIR always returns 72DPI for the screen (I may be incorrect on that point, however). It is fairly easy to do on mobile, though, assuming AIR returns the proper DPI (retina iPads did not return the correct DPIs prior to AIR 3.3, I believe).

Basically, you convert inches to pixels simply by multiplying by the DPI.

```
var dpi:Number = Capabilities.screenDPI; //unnecessary to save local version, just easier to reference
var heightCM:Number = 5;
var widthCM:Number = 5;

var widthPixels:Number, heightPixels:Number;
var heightIn:Number = cmToInches( heightCM );
var widthIn:Number = cmToInches( widthCM );

widthPixels = widthIn * dpi;
heightPixels = heightIn * dpi;

function cmToInches( value:Number ):Number {
    return value * .393701;
}
```

That will take a size (I built it for height and width, but you can adapt it to your needs) in centimeters, convert it to inches, and then convert it to pixels. You'd obviously want to turn that into a neat static Util method, but it would do the trick.

If you want, I created a Flex application last year to try and understand how AIR handles DPI differences. It just draws a red rectangle to a specific size on screen using on-screen sliders to determine the size (in inches). I don't have it here at work, but I could post the code when I get home.

Again, I do not believe this will work in desktop applications due to AIR always reporting 72 DPI. I hope I am wrong, but I do not believe I am.